# Why do we need a container for 3D in CSS3?

Tags: html, css, 3d

I was learning CSS3 3D, and from the tutorials they all say the we need a container, i thought that `<html>` or `<head>`  or `<body>` can be by default containers, since they always are in the upper tree of markup?

Why is `transform: perspective()` is needed to 'activate' the 3D, isent it a real 3D when we use only `transform: rotateZ()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need it to fix the angle of the "eye". With perspective, every element share the same viewer.

A definition I liked from [Safari's doc](https://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/) :

> The interesting thing about -webkit-perspective is that it does not affect the element directly. Instead, it affects the appearance of the 3D transforms on the transformed descendants of that element; you can think of it as adding a transform that gets multiplied into the descendant transforms. **This allows those descendants to all share the same perspective as they move around.**
>
> We’ve described how you can assign 3D transforms to elements and make them look three-dimensional with some perspective. However, so far, all the effects are really just painting effects. Those transformed children are still rendering into the plane of their parent; in other words, they are flattened.

You can find a great article about this [here](http://www.html5-css3.fr/css3/transformations-3d-css3) [FR].

[image: perspective]

*Sorry it is in my language, I will try to find another picture in english*

more info :

- [from Opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/understanding-3d-transforms/)
- [By css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/)

Comment: ohhhh so because it affects only the children and not itself?

Comment: Another quote for you `Please note the perspective property doesn't affect how the element is rendered; it simply enables a 3D-space for children elements. This is the main difference between the transform: perspective() function and the perspective property.` from CSS-Tricks :)